# Shutter not working anymore after the last update on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, screenshot, shutter

Last night I installed the latest updates, and this morning when I needed to make a screenshot I opened Shutter, but it immediately freezes and consumes abnormal CPU resources of over 40%.

I cannot press any button in Shutter, I receive a `Shutter is not responding` window after 10-20 seconds.

Any idea how I could fix this?

I uninstalled shutter with `purge`, installed again, but still get the problem. It's worth mentioning that some sort of cache memory remains even after purge because when I open Shutter after the reinstall I can still see some of the old images I had used before uninstall.

Any idea how could I remove this cache memory related to Shutter? Maybe that can fix the issue, whatever that is.

Comment: Worth mentioning that there's only a correlation between the updates and Shutter freezing. I'm not saying that the updates caused the freezing, although I don't exclude this scenario.

Comment: I was already on Xorg. Changed to Xorg after upgrading to 17.10 and there were problems with the screenshot software. I think we had a little chat on that issue too.  :)

Comment: I managed to fix this anyway, but I still don't know what was causing it. (see my answer below)

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve this by opening an image with Shutter. I took the following steps:

1. Right click on an image.
2. Click `Open With Other Application`.
3. Select `Shutter`.

I really don't know what was causing this. I thought for a second that maybe there's something still on pending, like an image opened somehow on Shutter's image editor (I had edited some images the day before this issues happened). Decided to try the steps above, and that fixed the problem. However, I really don't know the cause. If someone could elucidate this, that'd be great.

Comment: Thanks for this tip!  I have had the same problem for a year or so, stopped using Shutter entirely. I found the `Open With Other Application` trick worked for a single session, but quit & reload normally => same problem. I noticed it always froze with something like "Loaded Pictures/Selection_123.png" visible. Deleting the named file and restarting lead to it freezing on the next file.  I deleted `Pictures/Selection_*` and now Shutter starts OK even from the normal app launcher.  So I've no real idea what the problem was except that deleting all my old screenshots seems to have fixed it :)