# Shutter editing of images produces fuzzy/bad/aliased images in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, gimp, screenshot, shutter, gnome-screenshot

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 on a laptop (my desktop does not have this problem and it is also Ubuntu 17.10). After that upgrade, when I use the shutter app, and edit the images, the images are really quite bad.  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling shutter and it does not fix it.

I am able to create screenshots from Gimp just fine without fuzzy/bad/aliased images.

Here is an example of a clean screenshot taken by Gimp:

[image]

Compare that with the one taken by shutter:

[image]

I have removed the shutter package and reinstalled it and it has no effect.

I've seen responses to other questions describing [switching back to Xorg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988307/shutter-not-working-anymore-after-the-last-update-on-ubuntu-17-10#comment1592557_988307) but I don't want to do that as that seems like squashing a gnat with a sledge hammer and might cause more problems elsewhere.

Current installed version is:

```
drunkard@thebar:~$ apt-cache --no-all-versions show shutter
Package: shutter
Architecture: all
Version: 0.93.1-2
Priority: optional
Section: universe/graphics
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Perl Group <pkg-perl-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 17228
Depends: libgtk2-perl, libglib-perl, libgnome2-perl, libgnome2-vfs-perl, libgnome2-wnck-perl, libgnome2-gconf-perl, liblocale-gettext-perl, libxml-simple-perl, libwww-mechanize-perl, libwww-perl, perlmagick, libx11-protocol-perl, librsvg2-common, libfile-basedir-perl, libfile-copy-recursive-perl, libproc-simple-perl, libfile-which-perl, libsort-naturally-perl, libgtk2-imageview-perl, libnet-dbus-perl, libgnome2-canvas-perl, imagemagick, libgtk2-unique-perl, libproc-processtable-perl, procps, xdg-utils, libpath-class-perl, libjson-perl, libjson-xs-perl, libnet-dropbox-api-perl, libx11-protocol-other-perl
Recommends: libgoo-canvas-perl, libgtk2-appindicator-perl
Suggests: gnome-web-photo, nautilus-sendto, libimage-exiftool-perl, libnet-dbus-glib-perl
Filename: pool/universe/s/shutter/shutter_0.93.1-2_all.deb
Size: 1579014
MD5sum: 236e5226ae05102a5abb381e0e371e06
SHA1: 4c1f97e9fa51adb4f732634d1dc0b8ce9e94c0c3
SHA256: 324ee3babb27725522e5133eb8756439ad792561fb8edbd0cab50cdd6688fcde
Homepage: http://shutter-project.org/
Description-en: feature-rich screenshot program
 Shutter is a feature-rich screenshot program. You can take a
 screenshot of a specific area, window, your whole screen, or even of
 a website - apply different effects to it, draw on it to highlight
 points, and then upload to an image hosting site, all within one
 window.
 .
 Features:
    * take a screenshot of your complete desktop, a rectangular area
      or capture a website
    * take screenshot directly or with a specified delay time
    * save the screenshots to a specified directory and name them in a
      convenient way (using special wild-cards)
    * Shutter is fully integrated into the GNOME Desktop (TrayIcon etc.)
    * generate thumbnails directly when you are taking a screenshot
      and set a size level in %
    * Shutter session collection
          o keep track of all screenshots during session
          o copy screeners to clipboard
          o print screenshots
          o delete screenshots
          o rename your file
    * upload your files directly to Image-Hosters (e.g. imgur.com), retrieve
      all the needed links and share them with others
    * edit your screenshots directly using the embedded drawing tool
Description-md5: eb41c72ded4c1e3d870a360edd74625e
```

I am able to use `gnome-screenshot` but I want to be able to edit the subsequent screenshot with arrows and text and that does not allow me to easily/quickly/efficiently do so (e.g., I have to repeatedly waste time opening the screenshot up in Inkscape with a lot of wasted motion).

Comment: Well, Ubuntu themselves are going to ditch Wayland for now and [switch back to Xorg](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2018/01/26/bionic-beaver-18-04-lts-to-use-xorg-by-default/) as the default session.

Comment: @pomsky Thanks. I may just have to live with gnome-screenshot+Inkscape as the workaround for now. Inkscape would be my preferred way to add annotations anyhow if it wasn't for the tons of extra steps for saving back as a PNG file. Seeing as how Shutter doesn't seem to have been updated since 2014 so might just be orphan-ware, maybe that is the right choice.

Comment: [Flameshot](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/01/flameshot-linux-screenshot-tool-annotation) looks pretty cool, but I haven't tried it. See if this works alright.

Comment: @pomsky That link to Flameshot shows a lot of comments complaining about packaging and I am looking for things I don't have to modify my /etc/apt config in order to load as it will get modified/removed/disabled upon the next Ubuntu update. Yes it does look cool, but from the page it shows it does not have the ability to add Text objects which is a must. Yes I have the skills to build it from source, but no I do not want that.